# Angular 2 karma unit test for subscriber error

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, observable

While running code coverage tests I noticed that I didn't cover error handling on subscriber functions. 
Function to test:

```
 getVersion() {
    return this.aboutService.getAPIVersion()
        .subscribe(
            info => {
                console.log('info', info);
            },
            error => {
                console.log('error', error);
            }
        );
}
```

This is function is in the component and it's calling function from service. I managed to write unit test for function from service with mockBackend abd MockError but I don;t know how to do that with wrapper(caller) function.

So far I mocked service with class but I am only covering response and not the errors:

```
class AboutServiceStub {
    getAPIVersion = jasmine.createSpy('getAPIVersion').and.callFake(
        this.fakedGetAPIVersion
    );

    fakedGetAPIVersion() {
        console.log('fakedGetAPIVersion');
        return Observable.of(new Object(version))
            .map(version => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(version)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same scenario where i needed to test the error case just for one test case(for the sake of code coverage).The approach i followed is 
1.Get the injected service into the test as follows

```
aboutService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AboutService);
```

2.Now override the method using

```
aboutService.getAPIVersion = () => Observable.throw('error');
```

SO for this particular test the method has been overridden.
The exact code might not work,This is something i remember on top of my head .

Comment: you are right, only in 1) step you should inject actual service e.g. AboutService. And ofcourse I should import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'. Thanks!

Comment: thank for the comment i have edited my answer so that it doesn't produce errors for others.